# Conexion de php y sql server

Tags: php

Cordial saludo, soy nuevo en la programacion con php y voy páso a paso.
Estoy utilizando XAMPP y deseo conectar php con sql server (ya descargue los drivers).
Mi primer ejercicio es lograr que se de la conexion.

Este es el codigo que tengo para dicha conexion

```
<?php
$severName="localhost";
$conectionInfo=array("Database">="dbControlFlota","UID">="usuario1","PWD">="pwdpp","characterSet">="UTP-8");
$con=sqlsrv_connect($severName,$conectionInfo);

if ($con) {
     echo "conexion extisa";
}
else{
    echo "fallo en la conexion";
    //para sacar en pantalla el error
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
} 
?>
```

este es el error que me sale cuando lo trato de ver en la web:

```
fallo en la conexionArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -8 [code] => -8 [2] => An invalid connection option key type was received. Option key types must be strings. [message] => An invalid connection option key type was received. Option key types must be strings. ) )
```

agradezco su me ayuden.

Comment: Para empezar, en `$conectionInfo` tienes declarado el array al revés! El símbolo que se usa en php para asignar valores a un array asociativo es `=>`, una *flecha*! no `>=` esto significa  *mayor o igual*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primero deberías asignar bien las keys del array es decir:

```
$conectionInfo=array("Database"=>"dbControlFlota","UID"=>"usuario1","PWD"=>"pwdpp","characterSet"=>"UTP-8");
```

las keys se asignan con "=>", tú has puesto ">=".

Comment: Cordial saludo. Muchas gracias por la informacion. Hice la correccion y me sigue saliendo un error fallo en la conexionArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -48 [code] => -48 [2] => The encoding 'UTP-8' is not a supported encoding for the CharacterSet connection option. [message] => The encoding 'UTP-8' is not a supported encoding for the CharacterSet connection option. ) )

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo.
Logre resolver mi problema de conexion al no poner en la variable $conectionInfo los datos de "characterSet"=>"UTP-8".
Realmente no se para que funciona estos datos, pero al quitarlos logre que se conectara.

este era la variable en un principio:

```
$conectionInfo=array("Database">="dbControlFlota","UID">="usuario1","PWD">="pwdpp","characterSet">="UTP-8");
```

y asi quedo al final

```
$conectionInfo=array("Database"=>"dbControlFlota","UID"=>"usuario1","PWD"=>"pwdpp")
```

Ya cuando me conecto en la web, me sale este mensaje: conexion exitosa

De esta forma confirmo que la conexion esta ok.